# reading resources in Java

Tags: java, swing, maven

I have an old java code which I have to port to maven build system.
For accessing resources the code uses org.jdesktop ResourceMap class as follows:

```
    ResourceMap resourceMap = getResourceMap();
    int messageTimeout = resourceMap.getInteger("StatusBar.messageTimeout");
```

which assumes resource folder is directly in the same folder as the class file that is calling it. However maven likes to copy resources to root of the jar file. Therefore ResourceMap class cant find it. What is the simplest solution to this? Is there a way to configure maven to copy resources folder not to the root of the jar but to a specific folder inside the jar? or can I configure ResourceMap to search the resource folder in somewhere else.

Comment: *"However maven likes to copy resources to root of the jar file."* Really? I'd find it really surprising if that was anything more than a 'default' location. As an aside, a resource in the root of the Jar can be found from any package easily by adding a leading `/` to the name. The `/` represents the root/top level of the class-path.

Comment: "Really?" dont you think this is a non appropriate response and a strong indicator of your internal insecurity?  if you believe the question is missing details or lacking capability just vote it negatively or comment to fix it.

Comment: *"dont you think this is a non appropriate response"* No, I don't. *"and a strong indicator of your internal insecurity?"* LOL! Read that back in a year or so. Hope it's as funny for you then, as it is for me now. :)

Comment: ..oh, and I wasn't thinking of down voting before, but since you raised that topic, it's made me rethink the value of doing so. I might get back to you on that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, put it under `src\main\resources\specific\folder\inside\the\jar`.

This is since `src\main\resources` is the maven default for included resources, and the path structure under that is reflected in the jar.